# how do I pass the √ untouched

Tags: python, python-3.x

is it possible to pass the `√` through this untouched or am i asking too much

```
import urllib.request
path = 'html'
links = 'links'
with open(links, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as links:
    for link in links: #for each link in the file
        print(link)
        with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as linker: #get the html
            print(linker)
            with open(path, 'ab') as f: #append the html to html
                f.write(linker.read())
```

links

```
https://myanimelist.net/anime/27899/Tokyo_Ghoul_√A
```

output

```
File "PYdown.py", line 7, in <module>
    with urllib.request.urlopen(link) as linker:
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1392, in https_open
    context=self._context, check_hostname=self._check_hostname)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1349, in do_open
    encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1254, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1265, in _send_request
    self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1132, in putrequest
    self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u221a' in position 29: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: I don't think this really is something you want anyway, you're making it pretty difficult for someone to call that url for no reason

Comment: @Sayse I How might the process be simplified to call this URL

Comment: @NimballDimpall, but does it work with `https://myanimelist.net/anime/27899/Tokyo_Ghoul_%E2%88%9AA`?

Comment: With URLs, it's important for Unicode characters to be presented in a way that the glyphs can't be mistaken for other similar-looking glyphs, so URLs are often reduced to the canonical form with % representations of non-ASCII characters.  You should read about [IDN homograph spoofing attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to quote Unicode chars in URL. You have file which contains list of urls you need to open, so you need to split each url *(using [`urllib.parse.urlsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlsplit))*, quote *(with [`urllib.parse.quote()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.quote))* host and every part of path *(to split paths you can use [`pathlib.PurePosixPath.parts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.PurePath.parts))* and then form URL back *(using  [`urllib.parse.urlunsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlunsplit))*.

```py
from pathlib import PurePosixPath
from urllib.parse import urlsplit, urlunsplit, quote, urlencode, parse_qsl


def normalize_url(url):
    splitted = urlsplit(url)  # split link
    path = PurePosixPath(splitted.path)  # initialize path
    parts = iter(path.parts)  # first element always "/"
    quoted_path = PurePosixPath(next(parts))  # "/"
    for part in parts:
        quoted_path /= quote(part)  # quote each part
    return urlunsplit((
        splitted.scheme,
        splitted.netloc.encode("idna").decode(),  # idna
        str(quoted_path),
        urlencode(parse_qsl(splitted.query)),  # force encode query
        splitted.fragment
    ))
```

Usage:

```py
links = (
    "https://myanimelist.net/anime/27899/Tokyo_Ghoul_√A",
    "https://stackoverflow.com/",
    "https://www.google.com/search?q=√2&client=firefox-b-d",
    "http://pfarmerü.com/"
)

print(*(normalize_url(link) for link in links), sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
https://myanimelist.net/anime/27899/Tokyo_Ghoul_%E2%88%9AA
https://stackoverflow.com/
https://www.google.com/search?q=%E2%88%9A2&client=firefox-b-d,
http://xn--pfarmer-t2a.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of getting python to read `√` as itself, I would have to translate the `√` to `%E2%88%9A` in order to get python to output `√`

credit
@Olvin Roght

Comment: "it's important for Unicode characters to be presented in a way that the glyphs can't be mistaken for other similar-looking glyphs, so URLs are often reduced to the canonical form with % representations of non-ASCII characters."



material https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack
credit @Wyck